# How to set properties in inherited widget class?

Tags: flutter

I would like to set my own theme in my custom AppBar in compiletime. How can I go about calling the base constructor with only some properties changed?

In my app I have my `CustomAppBar` which is a parent of `HomeAppBar`. `CustomAppBar` inherits from `AppBar` and sets the background color to purple. `HomeAppbar` will set the title to `Text("Welcome")`

However changing the property doesn't seem to work:

```dart
class CommonAppBar extends AppBar {
  CommonAppBar() {
    super.appBartheme = AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.purple);
  }
}
```

Note that I am not changing them dynamically, I am describing these inherited widgets in compile time and I don't plan on changing any of the widgets dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
class CommonAppBar extends AppBar {
  CommonAppBar() : super(appBartheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.purple));
}
```